# Create a device to device connection with Socket over wifi

Tags: android, sockets

It's possible under Android to open a socket between two (or more) devices connected to the same wifi network ?
assuming of course that each device knows ip addresses of all other devices connected to wifi

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Why do you think it may not be possible?

Comment: i just want a confirm :) i've always used socket only from desktop apps

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [ip multicast idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast). For Android take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MulticastSocket.html)